# How to Disable cuDNN or force it to have deterministic behavior when using Keras with TensorFlow backend?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras with TensorFlow backend on GPU. How can I disable cuDNN or force it to have deterministic behavior?

There is a clear way for Theano backend as mentioned here:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2479

But I cannot find a similar way for TensorFlow. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow does not currently guarantee deterministic behavior for all it's operation.

You can find the clear explanation from these posts [1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41906) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50744565/how-to-handle-non-determinism-when-training-on-a-gpu).